# Go Rod If Button

Tags: go, if-statement, button, element

Trying to determine if a particular button exists on a page, if the button doesn't exist this code seems to freeze instead of continuing. Any ideas what options there might be to determine if the button exists or not on a page without the code stopping? :)

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/go-rod/rod"
)

func main() {

    urlSlice := []string{
        "https://www.amd.com/en/direct-buy/5450881700/us",
        "https://www.amd.com/en/direct-buy/5458373400/us",
    }

    for {

        for _, url := range urlSlice {

            page := rod.New().MustConnect().MustPage(url)

            btn := page.MustElement("#product-details-info > div.container > div > div > div.product-page-description.col-flex-lg-5.col-flex-sm-12 > button")

            if btn.MustText() == " ADD TO CART" {

                log.Printf(
                    "%s \t %s",
                    page.MustInfo().Title,
                    btn.MustText(),
                )

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to have the outer infinite for loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
btn := page.Timeout(10 * time.Second).MustElement("#product-details-info > div.container > div > div > div.product-page-description.col-flex-lg-5.col-flex-sm-12 > button")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but if anyone wanders here, here's how I solved this kind of problem:

I used .MustElements(...) to get all the buttons and then in a loop I checked the buttons' .MustText() value if any of them is matching to what I'm looking for.

```
buttons := page.MustElements("button")
for _, b := range buttons {
    t, err := b.Text()
    if err != nil {
      // error handling
    }
    if t == " ADD TO CART" {
        // Do what you need to do 
        log.Printf(
                "%s \t %s",
                page.MustInfo().Title,
                btn.MustText(),
        )
        break
    }
}
```

Of course it would be good if there would be some kind of explicit functionality that tests if a given element exists or not.